# Unity exception JDK not found

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

today I tried to install unity (2020.1.4f1) with the Unity Hub.

I have selected the following modules:

- Android Build Support (Android SDK & NDK Tools | OpenJDK)
- iOS Build Support
- Universal Windows Platform Build Support
- WebGL Build Support
- Windows Build Support (IL2CPP)
- Documentation

The installation is successfully completed.
But after I want to build an Android App (.apk) an error ouccurs.
The error from unity descripes that the JDK module is missing.

I tried to install the JDK manually from oracle.
Firstly I tried the newest JDK (jdk-8u261-windows-x64.exe) but this does not solve the problem.
Secondly I tried an older JDK version (jdk-8u251-windows-x64.exe) but even this one does not solve the problem.

I had set the Java envrionment variable manually, but wihtout success.

I installed Android Studio, but without success.

I hope there is someone who can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with the following solution.

1. I have run the Unity Hub with administrator rights.
2. I selected the system partition (in my case the C: drive) as installation directory (previously I had used the documents directory for installation)

I believe there was an approval problem with the installation process.